# Help with capturing with regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this list:

```
foo chef.rb baz
bar cucumber.rb bar
baz gem.rb foo
```

I want to capture all the names without .rb.

My current regexp looks like this:

```
/([^\s](?:.)*?.(?:rb))/i
```

But it captures the .rb too.

How do I capture just the base name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex instead:

```
/(\w*?)\.rb\s*.*/i
```

And your base-name will be in the 1st capture group.

See it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/QXu6OsiQKc).

Comment: Hmm weird, it should work, I donno why it dropped the first letter in the basename: hef, ucumber, gem, it etc.

Comment: @ajsie It shouldn't (see link). Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: @NullUserException: Look at my update. I forgot to tell you there are letters before and after the filenames. Could you customize your regexp to that?

Comment: @ajsie Regex updated, though now I am not as confident on it. You might want to throw some test cases at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit simpler:  `/(\S+).rb(?:$|\s)/`

Any non-space chars followed by .rb followed by either the end of line or a space.